# Square of a Ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $R$ be a ring (not necessarily unital) generated by some element $r$; i.e., $R = (r) = \{rx + nr \mid x \in R, n \in \Bbb{Z}\}$. Is the following true:

> $R^2 = R$ if and only if $r = \sum_{i=1}^n a_i b_i$ for some $n \in \Bbb{N}$ and $a_i, b_i \in R$, where 
>   $$R^2 = \{ \sum_{i=1}^k x_i y_i \mid k \in \Bbb{N}, x_i,y_i \in R\}$$

I think the following is a proof, but I would appreciate a critique:

> If $R^2 = R$, then trivially $r$ can be written as a finite sum of products of elements in $R$. Now suppose that $r = \sum_{i=1}^n a_i b_i$. If $y \in R$, then there exist an $x \in R$ and $n \in \Bbb{Z}$ such that $y = rx + nr = (\sum_{i=1}^n a_i b_i)x + n(\sum_{i=1}^n a_i b_i) = \sum_{i=1}^n a_i c_i + \sum_{i=1}^n a_i d_i = \sum_{i=1}^n a_i (c_i + d_i) \in R^2$.

**EDIT:**

If the above is right, I believe the following would be a corollary. Let $E$ denote the ring of even integers, and suppose that $2 = \sum_{i=1}^n a_i b_i$ for some $n \in \Bbb{N}$ and even integers $a_i$ and $b_i$. Then $a_i = 2k_i$ and $b_i = 2 \ell_i$ and therefore $2 = \sum (2k_i)(2 \ell_i)$ becomes $1 = 2 \left( \sum k_i \ell_i \right)$, which is a contradiction since $1$ is not even. Hence $E^2 \neq E$.